# Data Unable to Meet Normality/Equality Assumptions

Tags: normal-distribution, variance

I've been working with a rather difficult data set for over a week with no real progress. I am trying to compare the effect of temperature (15, 20, 25, 28, 30 degrees) on development time. The problem is the data is very non-normal and the variance unequal despite many transformations. What I have observed is as temperature decreases the variance increases quite substantially. For example, at 30 degrees the organism basically develops at 7 or 8 days but at 15 degrees the range of development can be 22-28 days ect. I've looked at running Kruskall-Wallis, Welsh ANOVA, but am still too concerned with the assumptions. Any advice? Here is my SAS Code if anyone wants to see what the issues are. Thanks!
http://www.filedropper.com/newtextdocument_21

Comment: How many observations for different temperatures  and more details? what is your end goal.

Comment: There are 90-270 observations depending on the temperature (776 across all 5). The end goal is to say development is different at specific temperatures through a multiple comparison test Dunns/Games Howell.

Comment: Is this not a time to event situation (time always positive) - perhaps with no cases where you did not yet observe the time?

Comment: @Erich say details about research design and objectives of study. Also insert self-study tag .

Comment: your study does not seem to be study that generates a final verdict. Do not enter the prohibited .area -Inferential statistics . Just explore and speak.

Answer (score 2):

When the assumptions of a regression model aren't met, I think it's better to adjust the method than the data.  That is, rather than transforming the data, use a method that does not make assumptions of equal variance.  You could use robust regression or quantile regression or maybe MARS ....

I wrote a paper about SAS methods for these: [Alternative methods of regression when OLS is not right](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279188432_Alternative_methods_of_regression_when_OLS_is_not_right)

Answer (score 2):

I have two thoughts in addition to those in Peter Flom's simple, straightforward, and helpful answer.

First, the biologist in me finds the increase in variability with lower temperature to be perhaps even more interesting than the change in average development time. Biological processes would generally be expected to slow down with lower temperature, but that wouldn't necessarily mean greater variance. Don't see the difference in variances just as a problem, see it as an opportunity.

Second, do consider the suggestion from Björn to treat this as a survival model (time-to-event analysis). Here the time to event would be the time to final development. Kaplan-Meier curves for your 5 temperatures might be quite informative.